# Epoch time conversion to a specific timezone

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to convert UNIX epoch time to Eastern Daylight Time.

```
std::time_t curtime = timestamp[i];
char buff[30];
strftime(buff, 30, strTimeStampFormat.c_str(), localtime(&curtime));
```

gives me conversion with a time offset between my time zone and New York. How this can be accomplished? I am thinking of recalculating somehow, but what time related WinAPIs should I use?

I tried this, but how to deal with daylight saving time

```
        std::time_t curtime = timestampint[i];
        char buff[30];
        struct tm * ptm;
        ptm = gmtime(&curtime);
        ptm->tm_hour = (ptm->tm_hour - 4) % 24;
        strftime(buff, 30, strTimeStampFormat.c_str(), ptm);
        timestampstring.push_back(std::string(buff));
```

Comment: How about `gmtime` instead of `localtime`?

Comment: @goodvibration added comment in the question . Daylight saving, how to deal with it? The offset will be minus 4 or minus 5

Comment: @dgrandm In `struct tm`, the member `tm_isdst` can judge if it is daylight saving time.Also you can use WinAPI [`GetTimeZoneInformation `](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-gettimezoneinformation?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to format a seconds-precision [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) stamp in local-time America/New_York, regardless of your computer's local time zone setting.  And I presume you want to do this in a thread-safe manner without resetting your computer's local time zone.

This can easily and safely be done in C++20 `<chrono>`.  I know that you don't have C++20 at the moment because it is not shipping yet.  But there exists a [free, open-source preview of C++20 `<chrono>`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

There's a couple of different options of how you could use this today, each with its own advantages and disadvantages.  First, here's what it looks like in C++20:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <fmt>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string
New_York(std::time_t currtime, std::string strTimeStampFormat = "{:%F %T %Z}")
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    sys_seconds tp{seconds{currtime}};
    zoned_seconds zt{"America/New_York", tp};
    ostringstream os;
    os << format(strTimeStampFormat, zt);
    return os.str();
}

int
main()
{
    std::cout << New_York(std::time_t{1599580658}) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
2020-09-08 11:57:38 EDT
```

The first step is to convert `time_t` into a `std::chrono::time_point<system_clock, seconds>`.  `sys_seconds` is a type alias for this type.

Next, a "pairing" of the [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and the `std::chrono::time_zone` `"America/New_York"` is formed, stored in a type called `zoned_seconds`.  This type is capable of translating between UTC and the local time in New York, taking into account daylight saving rules, and even changes in those rules dating back a century.

Finally you can format this `zoned_time` using familiar formatting flags that you've used with `strftime`.

This program does not care what your computer's current local time zone is set to, nor does it change that global.  A single program can safely format to multiple time zones, even in separate concurrent threads.

To do this today, with C++11, C++14 or C++17, the [free, open-source preview of C++20 `<chrono>`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) can be used, but it *will* [require some installation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation).  There are Windows-specific instructions at that link.  The source code changes slightly:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string
New_York(std::time_t currtime, std::string strTimeStampFormat = "%F %T %Z")
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    sys_seconds tp{seconds{currtime}};
    zoned_seconds zt{"America/New_York", tp};
    ostringstream os;
    os << format(strTimeStampFormat, zt);
    return os.str();
}
```

- Change `#include <fmt>` to `#include "date/tz.h"`.
- Drop the curly braces and `:` from the format string.
- Add `using namespace date;`.

The use and output are the same as before.

The installation involves compiling a single source file (tz.cpp) and installing [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) and [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) (if you haven't already done so).

There's a second option that requires no installation whatsoever.  It is a subset of the [preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) that is header-only.  The downside is that it models America/New_York only back to 2007.  And it uses an additional header to model POSIX time zones which will not be part of C++20.  Though this header will be compatible with C++20.  Here is what it looks like:

```
#include "date/ptz.h"

std::string
New_York(std::time_t currtime, std::string strTimeStampFormat = "%F %T %Z")
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    sys_seconds tp{seconds{currtime}};
    Posix::time_zone tz{"EST5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0"};
    zoned_time<seconds, Posix::time_zone> zt{tz, tp};
    ostringstream os;
    os << format(strTimeStampFormat, zt);
    return os.str();
}
```

- The header changes to `"date/ptz.h"`.
- Instead of using a standard (or pre-standard) `time_zone`, a custom `time_zone` is implemented in `ptz.h` and *that* is installed into a seconds-precision `zoned_time`.

The string `"EST5EDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0"` is a POSIX model of New York daylight saving rules from 2007 to the present.  This program will easily port to C++20, but will continue to need the header-only library in `date/ptz.h` to model the `Posix::time_zone`.

If you're using C++17 or later, then the declaration/definition of `zt` can be simplified to:

```
    zoned_time zt{tz, tp};
```

as the template parameters can be deduced by the constructor arguments.

The use and output are the same as before.

```
2020-09-08 11:57:38 EDT
```

Answer (score 0):

My case turned out to be a simple one. A separate API provided meta information including keypair "gmtoffset":"-14400". So making additional API call, parsing json and extracting GMT offset fixed it. The above code however can be used as a fallback.